# Side by side fixed divs - one is overriding the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/justinturner/pen/VjyWJE

The linked codepen has a fixed header div.

I'm using javascript to add a menu div on the left when the hamburger icon is clicked. This is also a fixed div.

When the menu div is added, the header div seems to revert to relative positioning, and jumps to the top of the main content div. Scroll down just a hair and then click the hamburger, you'll see what I mean.

What issue am I running into here? When a user clicks the hamburger, I want the header to remain fixed and translate directly to the right like the rest of the content.

```
<em>too much code to paste</em>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the **[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/)** and other **[similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596475/position-fixed-not-woking-when-parent-has-the-transform-css-property)** here on SO, fixed elements and translates don't *"play"* well together.

> As a workaround you could:
>
> 1) Use transitions (eg. on the left property) instead of transform (translateX)
>
> 2) Remove the position:fixed button from the container which uses transforms

Following the first suggestions from above (using `left` instead of `translateX`), edit your code to the following and the issue should no longer persist.

```
.o-wrapper.has-push-left {
    left: 300px;
}
.o-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 0.3s;
}

#header-wrapper {
  transition: left 0.3s;
}

.has-push-left #header-wrapper {
  left: 300px;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/edh6302r/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your fiddle, it's still happening. Scroll down a bit, click the hamburger, and the nav jumps up to the top of the page. Scroll down just a hair (like 10 px) to see it in action.

Comment: @JustinTurner please see updated answer, I believe the cause is how `translateX` and elements with `position: fixed` "play" together - [the demo in the updated section](https://jsfiddle.net/edh6302r/1/) show how to use the `left` property instead and not have to mess with `padding` and `margin`

Comment: Thanks again, let me digest this for minute, but I think you nailed it.